# How to input a competed word instead of single word to fasttext model

Tags: python, similarity, word-embedding, fasttext

I am using fasttext for word similarity purpose. I input a txt file which has a word in each line. The text format is string.

ex:
iphone 8 \n
apple hkd \n
billie jean jh audio \n
anafi fcc mode \n
smartone promotion \n
zenfone 5 price \n
brands of smartphones \n

But when I enter "iphone" to trained model in order to get the similarity results, it returns a singe word such as:

('買iphone', 0.7245190143585205), 
('"iphone', 0.6674467325210571), 
('iphone.', 0.6550431251525879), 
('piphone', 0.6026722192764282),
.....
('xs', 0.38547301292419434), 
('iph0ne', 0.37973055243492126), 
('hybrid', 0.3791016936302185), 
('cellphone', 0.37475910782814026), 
('xr', 0.3736417889595032)

I expect the output should have completed word like "iphone 8", "iphone xr".

Comment: But there is more than one word in some lines, e.g. "billie jean".

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me.

Do you use your txt file to train a model?
Instead, are you using pretrained word embeddings?

Comment: @mkrieger1 yes, so the word "billie jean" should be a "phrase"? I mean a single word here is like iphone instead of iphone 8.

Comment: @Anakin87 I use my own txt file to train a model. And the txt file is a bunch of keywords. They are not sentence, just product's name.